# How to fix SMTP authenticated mail going to spam using PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, spf

We have a website on a domain (domain1.com). We want to send an email from this website using PHPMailer. We are authenticating against an SMTP server with 1&1 Ionos (smtp.ionos.co.uk). This SMTP server is not for domain1.com, but instead of domain2.com.

The reason why the website is on domain1.com but we are trying to send through domain2.com's mail server is because for some reason our client's IT support can't give us SMTP for domain1.com.

When we send an email from domain1.com using domain2.com's SMTP, it goes to the junk/spam folder.

I believed when sending through a valid SMTP server, it would arrive in the inbox. We haven't setup SPF records as I'm unsure what it should be:

1. Should I be adding the webserver to it, or the smtp server?
2. Should the SPF record be added to domain2.com's dns?

I noticed I also receive an SCL of 5.

```php
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.ionos.co.uk';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'website@domain2.com';
    $mail->Password   = '[PASSWORD]';
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('website@domain2.com', 'Sender');
    $mail->addAddress('info@domain3.com', 'Receiver');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
```

I expected the outcome to be that the email sent to info@domain3.com is received in the inbox, with the sender being website@domain2.com.

The actual result is it arrives in the junk/spam folder.

**Below is the output from PHPMailer:**
(the domains we are using have been replaced with domain1.com and domain2.com.

```
2019-07-19 12:51:12 Connection: opening to smtp.ionos.co.uk:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2019-07-19 12:51:12 Connection: opened
2019-07-19 12:51:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 kundenserver.de (mreue010) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
2019-07-19 12:51:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO domain1.com
2019-07-19 12:51:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-kundenserver.de Hello domain1.com [109.228.60.45]250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN250-SIZE 69920427250 STARTTLS
2019-07-19 12:51:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 OK
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO domain1.com
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-kundenserver.de Hello domain1.com [109.228.60.45]250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN250 SIZE 69920427
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<website@domain2.com>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Requested mail action okay, completed
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<info@domain3.com>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 12:51:12 +0000
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Receiver <info@domain3.com>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Sender <website@domain2.com>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Here is the subject
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <pBl5X5mLOx1thDYn6AUiNl4bjQ670HqkyflaaOGMH9I@domain1.com>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_pBl5X5mLOx1thDYn6AUiNl4bjQ670HqkyflaaOGMH9I"
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_pBl5X5mLOx1thDYn6AUiNl4bjQ670HqkyflaaOGMH9I
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_pBl5X5mLOx1thDYn6AUiNl4bjQ670HqkyflaaOGMH9I
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_pBl5X5mLOx1thDYn6AUiNl4bjQ670HqkyflaaOGMH9I--
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=1MHXWL-1havq40lUn-00DZMt
2019-07-19 12:51:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-07-19 12:51:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 kundenserver.de Service closing transmission channel
2019-07-19 12:51:13 Connection: closed
Message has been sent
```

**And here is the header of the email received:**

```
Received: from CWXP265MB1255.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:401:53::17)
 by CWLP265MB1252.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS via
 CWLP265CA0125.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Fri, 19 Jul 2019 08:48:43 +0000
Received: from LO2P265CA0346.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (20.176.151.150) by
 CWXP265MB1255.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (20.176.46.18) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.2073.14; Fri, 19 Jul 2019 08:48:41 +0000
Received: from LO2GBR01FT016.eop-gbr01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7e15::205) by LO2P265CA0346.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10a6:600:d::22) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384) id 15.20.2094.14 via Frontend
 Transport; Fri, 19 Jul 2019 08:48:41 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is 212.227.126.130)
 smtp.mailfrom=domain2.com; domain3.com; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;domain3.com; dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=domain2.com;compauth=fail reason=001
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: domain2.com does not
 designate permitted sender hosts)
Received: from mout.kundenserver.de (212.227.126.130) by
 LO2GBR01FT016.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.42.102) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384) id
 15.20.2052.18 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 19 Jul 2019 08:48:41 +0000
Received: from domain1.com ([REDACTED]) by mrelayeu.kundenserver.de
 (mreue011 [213.165.67.99]) with ESMTPSA (Nemesis) id
 1Mt7Ll-1ih3S51mbR-00tR6X; Fri, 19 Jul 2019 10:48:40 +0200
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 08:48:40 +0000
To: Domain 3 <info@domain3.com>
From: Domain 2 <website@domain2.com>
Reply-To: Sender <support@domain3.com>
Subject: New Contact Form Submission
Message-ID: <Lf43d2831QWJXJRRec3pYAMiqXeMEtR7loF8JA@domain1.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_Lf43d2831QWJXJRRec3pYAMiqXeMEtR7loF8JA"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Provags-ID: V03:K1:e/W6m6DkyNXu1mwskQVZafYuaf1derI1aHb9EuWqPjAglIOY4mh
 kRjEKttXX634TcdJ0p/Yvpsf3Nbl4omvZt99cEY5pLB0//UzqWv+CC5z5rFkFuZ70x9EFsW
 bDk45ag6kVycT/z99bOVw28vh/zkWhXHet2C7WEhIP4adMWRFHVaqC/KuD6sLxXWoMUgmFX
 5Eu5i0eRCB7DFYJPqERZg==
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-UI-Out-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V03:K0:bcCEfwvDvho=:QIbCoiJzwuVrjP01f19XbK
 InQfJ96bF+Eocb7UwmE0rt74CsTThRrsNuQdrynWN0B02skkSilLqc4YvdydsLKi9jdp4llrm
 YEWgkovXgWg9Px0K/EwyjtT4fe2hrZiWZBko/T1hpnF9d6/lii+ZKOOAjZ9A316pfQ/QfpOrU
 6c1gSxCIfcRbCNEmS4Fe28iTZoyDpgzxgDQ1F0vhZhg2YQqDRGAfsl8W7WtZc8LakMnySeazH
 aet1iK0TgIqcRv6wluwUWUuS/FDNuk/0w7JlLnFeOpc0MPUodzfocYWyUG4G+Uty7nasnWBj0
 uuyo5WqwQ84ezn/If9c+VRJ/BD+5FsoU+x5MMgIZePjiIMOWZKnbGEzxszHRXLSEwXanWmvrz
 uKJR0K4gygHtzam0Qb5MsvXw1t1sPiL0ZVZLwFg8NDjo/iI4TffVrqb2gVq3njKo7HUqsgb45
 Kb87xdG4AKVMGHo0ZBNnWwt9VRCuqEOMKRQHKNH9F5Q1unKzg2frcC5g0cTf2iScSa7419tdq
 yS5pzfuZSi+LbraS8e8vPqYIs6UtmgbCVnBqGJ6tPHbLGVpxhvSdRPvfiLp6t9BTiDwrYuRZ9
 d21og5fi2mHtvIN7akFo1vF/H1MlCcNx7sxThJXvzWLuPM7QvtO6O4bCGjX4fG3VufEGQ+Gl9
 mR22XhQtycdwZqfc7m9fI86VFgtLfKhcyq+J78livGqKD60wEakXALLN1rQesdIrGhOuFFcyk
 VnWMkV/8m3zbXisMLNViHmKZ8N1cxaLDO97TmywwCE+m53sbVOFWRarREkUYWRJ73qdiDRi6j
 vokIIXk
Return-Path: website@domain2.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 19 Jul 2019 08:48:41.5122
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 e5cc4072-a21c-491e-23f6-08d70c25e668
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: a22d5c75-6de1-4404-8670-f8b904f670b7:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:212.227.126.130;IPV:NLI;CTRY:DE;EFV:NLI;SFV:SPM;SFS:(2980300002)(428003)(52294003)(199004)(189003)(43066004)(36756003)(3480700005)(9686003)(67896002)(55016002)(63394003)(5566004)(71850400003)(7596002)(305945005)(6916009)(40080500001)(7636002)(2160300002)(5660300002)(122186004)(8676002)(54206008)(86362001)(5000100001)(246002)(2870700001)(53416004)(16003)(356004)(71816002)(4326008)(1096003)(7696005)(50226002)(23466002)(107886003)(69370400003);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:5;SRVR:CWXP265MB1255;H:mout.kundenserver.de;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;PTR:mout.kundenserver.de;A:1;MX:1;CAT:SPOOF;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 LO2GBR01FT016.eop-gbr01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: e5cc4072-a21c-491e-23f6-08d70c25e668
X-Microsoft-Antispam:
 BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(2390118)(7020095)(4652040)(5600148)(711020)(4605104)(71702078);SRVR:CWXP265MB1255;
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: CWXP265MB1255:
X-MS-Oob-TLC-OOBClassifiers: OLM:1051;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 6
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 19 Jul 2019 08:48:41.4011
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: e5cc4072-a21c-491e-23f6-08d70c25e668
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: a22d5c75-6de1-4404-8670-f8b904f670b7
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: CWXP265MB1255
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:02.1609191
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.2073.000
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    ucf:0;jmr:1;ex:0;auth:0;dest:J;ENG:(20160513016)(750119)(520011016)(944506303)(944626516);
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    =?us-ascii?Q?530gbum92oE5lxvxGHFjKTvwkNuNbrN4ZTsC9nRXRvWpPqm+01yKW0yUD2ow?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?5U9/4DgeElUN3h75zsB43re/jDU2tjLnrrnb+3Tsib4iSwRB0+lALuJ9SuH5?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?DBByCazGMIO8rOPoz+C5/SUMvAVbj3UkCq+8BataVN0o4KMcEy0ZURngr+2p?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?klq26wdJ5vZYBWaocbnWiYYU5lH2creeZrU1E+mP/vSsm5/aPrJFxorLMsO3?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?2uYKWb7SJlBvCm8xAUCXEG7loXVeiAtgAZIIxeiINyVHkdE1tVst3XUazndP?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?2T7BocHQe7k88O/OUZMMtelSJFTPWs7fdRyA42DETNxqDMFuLR70YrxjKEwU?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?CXm6obMxzRhAYdKzzuYCVq/DjggHe970d2EBf976pAILp8fG0qttHBgESesT?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?iN3WkgYGE+cgSVRhkE4TVNYjLreDlv2Pm768AQanWbpxdfnGCYPk2Zj72yoy?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Ta65m/8oDLgXKPy3/iZhsR41Si3G1XrO4CJZaNzugt5XtzpL8mWoU0/gCWkZ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?opdAoFE6m+lMacycR6f+W5oMLc00uX3uHOmLi2pwgNkMcUj9PXIIyBXUMG7s?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?T4D3569bIIs33fP/7FPHbx/hI7JrngpYWi4mJpSm4ZlYFVnNZ82/ijfu615x?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?gIMhrRXC/3EpSyzFK0ywwz7xEikT7yKHTflnTU+Zin3wg0j9E7CLdUw9QdmS?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?CSaBLaGOiH+x7J/dvRwRFl2NRbg9SOmyX0opCz68Dgz34b6sQe9lEtn2CWiq?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?v1Ou+SJbRbLxgjRwQgXKIIiQZMHaRkxIf4ZHJh5qOk2d2cDEV5hvurtm7BfM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?TNrvN2efsEdRPJLWyemkNGSVSNnTmWn0aoKRYo6V3XHaqDnXSjru0Kve3n4P?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?BHEAvhLJVl2VGTM4ssaCFjYVmt5/BZz6Gq5mKpCDq0YMY7kHmP2rm2L56FVY?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?QBTiR/gU7G6kZhSI3cBwCbciD+taeKMSTDfI21xukDFvY3IV8/6um0it3S+a?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?SrQKWB4QXSKvk5sQHmAsdIJI0/c3W/B5oDQAbuWguY412dFpp7/JxuOx0IIQ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?YrBEYO/VyVbPVmL10t3RoQFzY2iXhaS0JAfnyT83K7YnzdsX72OpouWZEXg0?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?36tfQZX5E3TwPDO/99+n2I7wwG8tlTJUTxKVfu8IXxlP5BSl+NhC7dbhuD9A?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?S8zbhasHUmx0AeBWpQlLKcdtBFo0zCWE9XNflupFacb9Ad0sxJc5cjfudOFj?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?GAlDHiP+D7aXQLeMKMbt10IR8Z2kgJZsaihwJK9Jcj/FcNWSm8hTOuGo1SXB?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?rsRun27MrxaIMeYeXdR4b7MqklBQXyo4BvZE9NmoNcD0XBqtb5oov7IBSO+Q?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?pl2oVMJpjKiA9VKTjXM+V2UgppO+/haWWca+ClxqACUyZSrpHps1QKzO5V1f?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?UazfEkWHkIDAsKHtAhdL0JDMne//UGffGO4YNFMyVSfXcGGnXxKBfnltF6wq?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ccjhtrWc6BG1zYE=3D?=
```

Comment: This is less of a programming issue and more of a server issue, so off-topic here. There are many reasons why an email could go into spam, ranging anywhere from headers, SPF and DKIM, and email content.

Comment: Thanks - I see what you mean. If it's not an issue with the code, I guess my question then should I had the webserver that's requesting an email to be sent through SMTP to the SPF record, or should adding the SMTP server to the SPF record be sufficient.

In other words, is the fact that I'm sending it from domain1.com irrelevant, as it's successfully authentication against a SMTP server. Is the issue between the SMTP server and the receiving mailserver?

Comment: From experience I am aware that if your domain name isn't using the correct MX records for the SMTP server the email provider (Gmail) can't authenticate that the server sending the email is related to @domain1.com. Until you resolve that it'll certainly go into spam.

Comment: So is the solution 1. To add the IP address of the webserver and the SMTP server to the SPF record of domain2.com, or 2. If sending form domain1.com, I should be authenticating and sending from an SMTP server related to domain1.com. What I'm trying to work out is what effects spam and what doesn't. I thought I should be able to send through an SMTP server unrelated to the web server's domain as long as you do it properly.

Comment: The SPF record is added to the domain of the sending server, which basically says "This IP is permitted to send out emails for this domain." So you need to add the IP of the SMTP server into the SPF record.

Comment: Thanks @aynber so in this case, the fact that it's the web-server requesting the SMTP server to send the email is irrelevant, and the web-server IP doesn't need to be in the SPF record as it's not the one sending the email. I will add the mail server to the SPF record of the sender domain and see if this improves.

Comment: There is no way to guarantee inbox placement. Even if you use SPF, sign with DKIM and set up DMARC, reverse DNS, etc (and you should set up those things as they do help), you can still end up in spam without any particular reason. This is especially true for gmail and similar services.